# Run git pull over all subdirectories windows command promt

Tags: windows, git, command-prompt

How can I update multiple git repositories from their shared parent's directory without cd'ing into each repo's root directory on windows 7 ?

I have the following which are all separate git repositories (not submodules):

```
c:\projects\repos\repo1
c:\projects\repos\repo2
c:\projects\repos\repo3
```

On linux I can use this bash script

```
find ~/projects/repos/ -type d -name .git \
| xargs -n 1 dirname \
| sort \
| while read line; do echo $line && cd $line && git pull origin $1 && echo ; done
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Windows Batch solution:

if you want to use this in .bat script use this:

```
for /D %%G in ("*") do (echo %%G) && (cd %%G) && (git pull origin) && (cd ..)
```

if it's just in the console:

```
for /D %G in ("*") do (echo %G) && (cd %G) && (git pull origin) && (cd ..)
```

Comment: Nice! Is there also a way to not have to identify myself with my passphrase for every repo?

Answer (score 13):

A cleaner and nicer way to do this, is a normal console command :

```
FOR /D %a IN (c:\projects\repos\*) do git -C %~fa pull
```

or in a .bat file

```
FOR /D %%a IN (c:\projects\repos\*) do git -C %%~fa pull
PAUSE
```

Or even a .bat file in the projects directory

```
FOR /D %%a IN (.\repos\*) do git -C %%~fa pull
PAUSE
```

Comment: Accepted answer dies if one of the pulls fail, which is sometimes what you want but I did not. This answer worked for me even if some pulls failed.

I used the generic form      FOR /D %a IN (*) do git -C %~fa pull

Answer (score 11):

You can use PowerShell script:

```
$dirs = Get-ChildItem -Path . | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer }
$back = pwd
foreach ($dir in $dirs)
{
    cd $dir.FullName
    echo $dir.FullName
    git pull origin
}   
cd $back.Path
```

Comment: Thank for your solution, it's possible do it without PowerShell just Windows Prompt?